# Dev environment brand new setup and getting this error: PluginManager: Failed to download plugin

Tags: windows, plugins

I installed twilio cli on a windows 11 machine with node 18.17 and npm 9.  When using twilio cli to start the project, the flex UI loads up fine, but the sample plugin gets a 504 error.

If I go to localhost:3000/plugins I see what I assume is the plugin manager.  But localhost:3000/plugins/plugin-sample.js can't be found (504 gateway timeout).  I can find that file hosted at localhost:3100/plugsin/plugin-sample.js

I'm not sure what I could be missing here.

I tried changing the pluginService to localhost:3100 but it seems the plugin manager is on :3000 while the plugin file is on :3100 (i dont know if this is intended or not).

Comment: I posted this through the twilio community and I thought that context would persist.  This is for creating a react plugin for twilio flex.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/quickstart/getting-started-plugin